Force feature branch to be ahead of target branch before merging in GitLab
I want that in GitLab Merge Requests are only allowed to be merged when the feature branch is n commits ahead and 0 commits behind the target branch.
is it possible to set this up in GitLab?

I think both the Merge commit with semi-linear history and fast-forward merge merge method options would basically check that?

I think neither requires the feature branch to be 0 commits behind.

Both of them require fast-forward merges to be possible. To my understanding, fast-forward merges are only possible if the feature branch is 0 commits behind the main branch.
If neither of those options work for you, I think you'll have to use custom status checks and create an external service where you can add some custom logic.
